# How to resolve error : time data 'False' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

When i'm trying to do an approve action that modify the hr.attendance fields via a modification request this error shows.I tried to search on the net about this error but the major answer was the format of database not the same with the code but in my case i saw the data of my database but i found the same format is used. Any idea on how can i fix this problem ?

hr.attendance

[image]

here is my code

```
 @api.multi
def modification_approval(self):     attend_signin_ids = self.env['hr.attendance'].search([('employee_id','=',self.employee_id.id)])
    check_in_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.time_check_in_1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
    check_out_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.time_check_out_1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
    for obj in attend_signin_ids:
        attendance_check_in_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(obj.check_in), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
        attendance_check_out_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(obj.check_out), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
        if (check_in_date == attendance_check_in_date):
            obj.write({'check_in': self.time_check_in_1,
                       'check_out': self.time_check_out_1})

    return self.write({
        'state': 'approved'
    })
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 651, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
raise value
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 693, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 937, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/openhrms/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 938, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/opt/openhrms/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 926, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/openhrms/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/openhrms/addons/sifast_attendance_modification_request/models/hr_attendance_modification_request.py", line 67, in modification_approval
attendance_check_out_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(obj.check_out),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'False' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the traceback you will see this line:

```
File "/opt/openhrms/addons/sifast_attendance_modification_request/models/hr_attendance_modification_request.py", line 67, in modification_approval
attendance_check_out_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(obj.check_out),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
```

This, combined with the error itself

```
ValueError: time data 'False' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
```

suggests that `obj.check_out` is the boolean `False` and not a date string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i update my question with a picture of the data of hr.attendance so you can notice that check_out is a datetime field

Comment: @Dhouha That screenshot is not helpful. It's a fact that `obj.check_out` is `False` in at least one iteration. Use a debugger or `print` calls to see why and when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Time data 'False' occurs when that field is not date string or it contains null value ie (obj.check_out), so it returns False value when it is called.So first make sure that field contains value when function is called.